# React Native - Pressable - Can't run sample code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i am trying to run the example code from react native you can find here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable

I allways get the error message: ***Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: %s.%s%s, undefined,  You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined
in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.***

can anyone tell me whats the problem here?

example code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Pressable, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const [timesPressed, setTimesPressed] = useState(0);

  let textLog = '';
  if (timesPressed > 1) {
    textLog = timesPressed + 'x onPress';
  } else if (timesPressed > 0) {
    textLog = 'onPress';
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Pressable
        onPress={() => {
          setTimesPressed((current) => current + 1);
        }}
        style={({ pressed }) => [
          {
            backgroundColor: pressed
              ? 'rgb(210, 230, 255)'
              : 'white'
          },
          styles.wrapperCustom
        ]}>
        {({ pressed }) => (
          <Text style={styles.text}>
            {pressed ? 'Pressed!' : 'Press Me'}
          </Text>
        )}
      </Pressable>
      <View style={styles.logBox}>
        <Text testID="pressable_press_console">{textLog}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    fontSize: 16
  },
  wrapperCustom: {
    borderRadius: 8,
    padding: 6
  },
  logBox: {
    padding: 20,
    margin: 10,
    borderWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    borderColor: '#f0f0f0',
    backgroundColor: '#f9f9f9'
  }
});

export default App;
```

Comment: Are you using expo?

Comment: yes i am using expo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pressable is not available in Expo yet, because expo does not support React Native v0.63 (yet).

Comment: ahhh ok. and whats the alternative? or how should i setup an new project

Comment: Try to use `TouchableOpacity`